# Android Multi-State ToggleButton check state

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-togglebutton

Im trying to build an application on my own with a multi-state toggle button and I want to check which state is selected.

Is there any method or something like that to check this?

I want to say that in simple toggles there's the method " isChecked(); ".
Note that i got 3 states inside the toggle.

1.Lowercase

2.Uppercase

3.Both

Comment: Multi State Toggle is not an Android widget. You must be using a Library, and you will have to look into that library's docs or code.

Comment: @lionscribe thanks for the help mate. I'll now look at the library's code

Answer (score 0):

Just try to implement above things using [jlhonora MultistateToggle Library](https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton/tree/master/multistatetogglebutton/src/org/honorato/multistatetogglebutton)

getValue() is the method which returns index number so that you can easily identify what user has selected

```
public class AddListingForm extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_listing_form);

    final MultiStateToggleButton toggleButton= (MultiStateToggleButton) 
this.findViewById(R.id.MSTB);

// With an array
   CharSequence[] states= new CharSequence[]{"Lowercase","Uppercase", 
"Both"};
    toggleButton.setElements(states);

    toggleButton.setOnValueChangedListener(new ToggleButton.OnValueChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(int position) {

            property_type = states[position].toString();

        }
    });

 int a=toggleButton.getValue(); 
  // if User selected Lowercase then you will  get value of a is 0 
 //  Similarly for Uppercase a will be 1 and for Both a will be 2

}
}
```